# How to access env variable with python command line and script?

Tags: python-2.7

How do we access linux environment variables with python command line ?

```
eg
export FILENAME=hi.txt
python -c 'import sys
output_file=open("/home/user/$FILENAME", "w+")
print >>output_file, "hi"
'
```

The issue we have is that $FILENAME isnt expanded to string "hi.txt" within the python script.

Is there a workaround ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`os.path.expandvars()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars).

```
with io.open(os.path.expandvars("/home/user/$FILENAME"), "w+") as output_file:
  print >>output_file, "hi"
```

Comment: Hi Ignacio thanks for responding. We found that $FILENAME is not found by python when we print os.environ but in our linux SHELL we can see that the FILENAME has value hi.txt. How can we cause our SHELL variables are seen by python inside its script then ?

Comment: Exporting it will allow subprocesses to see the variable. If the Python script is not running in a subprocess then it will never see the variable.